# Can a list with repeating values be converted into a multiset in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, multiset

I am having two lists with repeating values and I wanted to take the intersection of the repeating values along with the values that have occurred only once in any one of the lists.
I am just a beginner and would love to hear simple suggestions!

Comment: Please share an example input/output and your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: `collections.Counter` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```
l1=[1,2,3,4]
l2=[1,2,5]
intersection=[value for value in l1 if value in l2]
for x in l1+l2:
    if x not in intersection: 
        intersection.append(x)
print(intersection)
```

Method 2

```
print(list(set(l1+l2)))
```